# JTextField getting stuck on specific text for ActionListener

Tags: java

I have a program where a JMenuButtonItem is supposed to be selected and an ActionListener updates a JTextField with whatever is selected.  However, it is only displaying what is pre-selected as `true` in buildPhonePackageMenu().  If `true` is not in the parameters, NO radio button is recognized as selected.
The buildPhoneModelMenu() appears to be working fine.

Can anyone help me figure out why one menu works and not the other?  I've been up 6 hours trying to figure it out.
Thanks!

```
    import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CellPhoneCalculator extends JFrame{

    private JMenuBar menuBar; //Menu bar to hold drop down menus.
    private JMenu fileMenu; //file menu
    private JMenu phonePackage; //menu containing phone packages and options
    private JMenu phoneModels; //menu containing cell phone models.
    private JMenuItem exit;//Exit button
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem package300; //300 minute cell phone package
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem package800; //800 minute cell phone package
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem package1500; //1500 minute cell phone package.
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem phone100;  //phone model 100
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem phone110; //phone model 110
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem phone200; //phone model 200
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem vmail; //voicemail option
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem text; //text messaging option

    private JLabel packageSelected;//Displays the text "Cell Phone Package:"
    private JLabel modelSelected; //Displays the text "Cell Phone Model:"
    private JLabel optionsSelected; //Displays the text "Options Selected:"
    private JLabel subtotal; //Displays the text "Subtotal."
    private JLabel tax; //Displays the text "Sales Tax (6%) :"
    private JLabel total; //Displays the text "Total:"
    private JTextField pSelected; //displays the selected cell phone package.
    private JTextField mSelected; //displays the selected cell phone model.
    private JTextField oSelectedV; //Displays the Voice Mail option selected.
    private JTextField oSelectedT; //Displays the Text option selected.
    private JTextField dspSub; //displays the subtotal
    private JTextField dspTax; //displays the sales tax amount on subtotal
    private JTextField dspTotal; //displays the total after tax.

    public CellPhoneCalculator()
    {
        //call the superclass constructor to instantiate a JFrame
        //with a String argument to be title.
        super("Cell Phone Package Pricing Calculator");

        //Exit on window close
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buildPricePane();//builds the price panel to go into content pane
        buildMenuBar();//Builds the menu bar.
        buildPhonePackageMenu();//Builds phone package menu
        buildFileMenu();//Builds the File Menu


        //pack method to resize JFrame.
        pack();
        //Set visibility of panel.
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildMenuBar()
    {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();//Create the menu bar

        buildFileMenu(); //build the file menu
        buildPhonePackageMenu();//build the phone package menu
        buildPhoneModelMenu();//build the phone model menu
        //Add the menus to the menuBar.
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(phonePackage);
        menuBar.add(phoneModels);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);//sets the menu bar for the window.
    }

    private void buildPhonePackageMenu()
    {
        phonePackage = new JMenu("Cell Phone Packages");//Drop down containing phone plan
                                                    //packages and options.

        //Make the radio buttons for cell phone packages.
        package300 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("300 minute package", true);
        package800 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("800 minute package");
        package1500 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("1500 minute package");

        //Register the action listener PackageListener with the radio buttons.
        package300.addActionListener(new PackageListener());
        package800.addActionListener(new PackageListener());
        package1500.addActionListener(new PackageListener());

        //Make new button group for packages so buttons are mutually exclusive.
        ButtonGroup packages = new ButtonGroup();

        //Add radio buttons to packages button group.
        packages.add(package300);
        packages.add(package800);
        packages.add(package1500);

        //Create phone option check boxes.
        vmail = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Voice Mail");
        text = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Text Mail");

        //Register Item Listener with check box options.
        vmail.addItemListener(new OptionsListener());
        text.addItemListener(new OptionsListener());

        //Add components to menu
        phonePackage.add(package300);
        phonePackage.add(package800);
        phonePackage.add(package1500);
        phonePackage.addSeparator();//Add a separator before phone options
        phonePackage.add(vmail);
        phonePackage.add(text);

    }

    private void buildFileMenu()
    {
        //Instantiate file drop down with text "File."
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        //Create exit button
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        //register action listener
        exit.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());
        //add exit menu item to menu
        fileMenu.add(exit);

    }
    /*
     * Build the menu to select the phone models.
     */
    private void buildPhoneModelMenu()
    {
        //Create Menu drop down with text "Phone Models."
        phoneModels = new JMenu("Phone Models");
        //Create new radio buttons in menu, with model 100 preselected.
        phone100 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Phone Model 100", true);
        phone110 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Phone Model 110");
        phone200 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Phone Model 200");

        //Register the ActionListener modelListener with the buttons.
        phone100.addActionListener(new ModelListener());
        phone110.addActionListener(new ModelListener());
        phone200.addActionListener(new ModelListener());

        //Create new phone model button group.
        ButtonGroup phoneModel = new ButtonGroup();
        //Add phone model radio buttons to button group, so they're selection is mutually exclusive.
        phoneModel.add(phone100);
        phoneModel.add(phone110);
        phoneModel.add(phone200);

        //Add the buttons to the menu.
        phoneModels.add(phone100);
        phoneModels.add(phone110);
        phoneModels.add(phone200);

    }
        private DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        /*
         * Construct the PricePane with all components.
         */
        public void buildPricePane()
        {
            //Create the JPanel object and assign to pricePanel.
            JPanel pricePanel = new JPanel();
            setLayout(new GridLayout(13,1));

            //Create the text labels for left hand column
            packageSelected = new JLabel("Cell Phone Package: ");
            modelSelected = new JLabel("Cell Phone Model: ");
            optionsSelected = new JLabel("Options Selected: ");
            subtotal = new JLabel("Subtotal: ");
            tax = new JLabel("Sales Tax (6%): ");
            total = new JLabel("Total: ");

            //Create the Un-Editable text fields to display selected radio button items
            pSelected = new JTextField("", 10);
            pSelected.setEditable(false);

            mSelected = new JTextField("", 10);
            mSelected.setEditable(false);

            //Create the Un-Editable text fields to display selected check box items.
            oSelectedV = new JTextField(10);
            oSelectedV.setEditable(false);
            oSelectedT = new JTextField(10);
            oSelectedT.setEditable(false);

            //Create the un-editable text fields to display subtotal, tax and total.
            dspSub = new JTextField("", 10);
            dspSub.setEditable(false);
            dspTax = new JTextField("", 10);
            dspTax.setEditable(false);
            dspTotal = new JTextField("", 10);
            dspTotal.setEditable(false);

            //Add the items and labels to JPanel.
            add(packageSelected);
            add(pSelected);
            add(modelSelected);
            add(mSelected);
            add(optionsSelected);
            add(oSelectedV);
            add(oSelectedT);
            add(subtotal);
            add(dspSub);
            add(tax);
            add(dspTax);
            add(total);
            add(dspTotal);

        }

    /*
     * ActionListener interface for the cell phone package radio buttons.
     * Sends text and prices to PricePane, to display and sum respectively.
     */
    private class PackageListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(package300.isSelected())
                pSelected.setText("300 minutes per month: $45.00 per month");//Sends display text
            if(package800.isSelected())
                pSelected.setText("800 minutes per month: $65.00 per month");
            if(package1500.isSelected())
                pSelected.setText("1500 minutes per month: $99.00 per month");

        }
    }
    /*
     * ItemListener interface for the cell phone options check boxes.
     */
    private class OptionsListener implements ItemListener
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            if(vmail.isSelected())
                oSelectedV.setText("Voice mail: $5.00 per month");
            if(text.isSelected())
                oSelectedT.setText("Text messaging: $10.00");
        }
    }
    /*
     * ActionListener for the cell phone model radio buttons.
     */
    private class ModelListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(phone100.isSelected())
                mSelected.setText("Model 100: $29.95");
            if(phone110.isSelected())
                mSelected.setText("Model 110: $49.95");
            if(phone200.isSelected())
                mSelected.setText("Model 200: $99.95");

        }
    }


    /*
     * ActionListener interface for exit button to close application.
     */
    private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    /*
     * Main function to launch GUI.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new CellPhoneCalculator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    buildPhonePackageMenu();//Builds phone package menu
```

This line in 
   public CellPhoneCalculator()

Needs to be removed.  I screwed up.  Disregard.

Comment: Consider deleting the question